# UITableView background is visible under cell when row actions are shown

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have `UITableView` with white colored section headers and dark cells. The table background is also white. This is done so that section headers look nice when the table is bouncing:

[image]

I added a couple of actions ([`UITableViewRowAction`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewrowaction)) to rows in this table. However, there is one problem: since the rows are dark, when I swipe to show row edit actions, there is a white gap between the first action:

[image]

(Note that both cell and its content view have the same dark background color set in the XIB file.)

After inspecting the view hierarchy I found that the cell is shrinked after action buttons are displayed and what I see through this gap is the actual table view.

Because I can't change the table view's background I tried adding a custom background view to it below all other views:

```
self.tableBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds];
self.tableBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.tableBackgroundView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleSize;
[self.tableView addSubview:self.tableBackgroundView];
[self.tableView sendSubviewToBack:self.tableBackgroundView];
```

However, it didn't work well.

Are there any other ways to "hide" the whitespace between cells and their edit actions?

Comment: @KKRocks What do you mean? If you're talking about the edit and clear buttons they are `UITableViewRowAction`: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewrowaction

Comment: yes i know but i want know how add this button...put that code so i can understand your problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to overcome this by adding a background for behind each cell inside `tableView:willDisplayCell:` (one per cell).

This is my final code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Remove background gaps on the left and right sides of row separators on iOS < 10.
    cell.backgroundColor = cell.contentView.backgroundColor;

    // Remove another gap in row background when swiping in to the left to start editing.
    CGRect cellFrame = [cell convertRect:cell.bounds toView:tableView];
    UIView *backgroundView = self.cellBackgroundViews[indexPath];
    if (backgroundView == nil) {
        backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        self.cellBackgroundViews[indexPath] = backgroundView;
    }
    backgroundView.frame = CGRectInset(cellFrame, 0, -1);
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = cell.contentView.backgroundColor;
    [self.tableView addSubview:backgroundView];
    [self.tableView sendSubviewToBack:backgroundView];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIView *backgroundView = self.cellBackgroundViews[indexPath];
    [backgroundView removeFromSuperview];
}
```